# Can I use the DLLs included in the nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I used Nuget package explorer to pack some third party DLLs into one package and published to my nuget server, many of my projects need refer to those third party DLLs and I don't want to add DLL references over and over again. With nuget I only need to install one package.
But after installing that package, i can see those DLLs in the packages folder, but I cannot use classes in those DLLs.
Is that possible to use classes in the DLLs of that nuget package?

Comment: Let me rephrase: You want to automatically add all Dll's of your package to all your projects?

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy i think op needs to add several third-party DLLs into one nuget and avoid writing "using DLL1;", "using DLL2;", "using DLL3;" in every class so write only "using MyNuget;" once and use the code from all added DLLs. Am i right?

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy yes, you are correct, but i want all of my dlls are packed in one nuget package

Comment: hi @tomwaitforitmy, let me clearify my issue, let's say i have three third-party dlls, a.dll, b.dll and c.dll, there are some public classes in the three dlls, now i use nuget package explorer to pack that three dlls into one package, let's say mypackage and published to my nuget server. now i create a new C# project, i add that package and want to use the classes in the three dlls in my new project, but so far i cannot use them.

Comment: Can you post your `csproj` file that contains `mypackage`? Because with the newer SDK-style projects/`<PackageReference>`, there should be no need to add assembly references.
And please also specify what you mean by _use_: do you want to avoid the `using` directive?